# Not loading on request from the json api in nativescript

Tags: javascript, json, nativescript

**main-page.xml**

```
<Page loaded="pageLoaded" class="page" xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd"
 xmlns:lv="nativescript-ui-listview" 
xmlns:Card="nativescript-cardview">
<ActionBar title="Home" class="action-bar">
    </ActionBar>
    <lv:RadListView id="ls" items="{{ dataItems }}" row="0" loadOnDemandMode="Auto"
        loadMoreDataRequested="{{onLoadMoreItemsRequested}}">
        <lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
 <Card:CardView class="card" elevation="40" radius="10" >
                <StackLayout class="card-layout" orientation="horizontal"  >
                    <StackLayout class="card-layout" orientation="vertical" >
                    <Label fontSize="20" text="{{ title }}" marginBottom="8" />
                 </StackLayout>
                </StackLayout>
            </Card:CardView>
        </lv:RadListView.itemTemplate>
    </lv:RadListView>
</Page>
```

**main-page.js**

```
var HomeViewModel = require("./main-view-model");
var homeViewModel = new HomeViewModel();
function pageLoaded(args) {
  var page = args.object;
   page.bindingContext = homeViewModel;
  listView = page.getViewById("ls");
  homeViewModel.initDataItems();
  homeViewModel.addMoreItemsFromSource(3);
  }
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

**main-view-model.js**

```
const httpModule = require("tns-core-modules/http");
var observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");
var ObservableArray = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable-array").ObservableArray;
var posts = require("./posts.json");
var url1="https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Janelle%20Mon%C3%A1e&prop=categories";
function HomeViewModel() {
  var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({

    _sourceDataItems: [],

    initDataItems: function () {
       *//This function is for local json Its working as expected. 
      this._sourceDataItems = new ObservableArray();
      for (let i = 0; i < posts.names.length; i++) {

        this._sourceDataItems.push({ name: posts.names[i] });
      }//*
    httpModule.request({
        url: url1,
        method: "GET"
    }).then((response) => {
        for( var i=0; i<response.length;i++){
       this. _sourceDataItems.push({title: response.query.pages.categorymembers[i].title})
    }  

    }, (e) => {
    });

      },

    dataItems: [],
    addMoreItemsFromSource: function (chunkSize) {

      let newItems = this._sourceDataItems.splice(0, chunkSize);
      this.dataItems = this.dataItems.concat(newItems);
    },

    onLoadMoreItemsRequested: function (args) {
      console.log("---load item called----");
      const that = new WeakRef(this);
      const listView = args.object;
      if (this._sourceDataItems.length > 0) {
        setTimeout(function () {
          that.get().addMoreItemsFromSource(3);
          listView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished();
        }, 4000);
        args.returnValue = true;
      } else {
        args.returnValue = false;
        listView.notifyLoadOnDemandFinished(false);
      }

    },
  });

  return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```

In My code snippet I am not able to fetch data from json api but from the local json getting the data. If I put json api data is not displaying and not giving error also. Please help me to fetch the data from api when load more data request.
https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&titles=Janelle%20Mon%C3%A1e&prop=categories, this is for demo while writing the function used fetch(), httpmodule.getjson() Its not working for all let me know where I commit mistake.

Comment: You have logical error in your code, the response is an object but your are trying to access it like an array.

Comment: How to fix this logical error where I need to change please let me know

Comment: please give me any answer for this please...

Comment: @Manoj please help me to fix this I am getting the result its showing blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I already mentioned, you are not parsing your data correctly.

This is how your JSON looks,

```
{
   ...
   "query":{
      "pages":{
         "13828397":{
            ...
            "categories":[
               {
                  "ns":14,
                  "title":"Category:1985 births"
               },
            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So you have to do,

```
var items = response.query.pages["13828397"].categories;
for( var i=0; i<items.length;i++){
   this._sourceDataItems.push({title: items[i].title})
}
```

Comment: What the correction you made in code its not displaying the data as expected. Its showing the blank page. Code is logically correct but data is not displaying. So please help me to fix this issue. I am sorry again disturbing to you. Here is the play ground sample https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=jMRqJH

Comment: I'm not sure why you are complicating your view model. You would need load on demand only when you load data chunk by chunk, but in your case you are loading everything at once. I simplified it and it works - https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=jMRqJH&v=3

Comment: If it's 2000+ I would agree you need load on demand but not 5, that's too small. You will have to do at least 20 or 50 in case of tablets.

Comment: Based on your previous inputs, I believe you have to interact with 2 different APIs one for paging and another for fetching data for the particular page. To be honest, you seem to lack knowledge in JavaScript, as I see your sample (v6) you have copied the NativeScript's load on demand example but that example won't simply suit your requirement. I'm sorry I can not code it for you completely. You will have to spend some time in understanding how JSON & JS Objects / Array work, how to traverse through them. That might help you to finish your requirement.

Comment: Thank you @ Manoj for your response and sorry for wasting your time..